# Using VBA, How do I access the Source Data property of the connection string?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an ODBC connection to an SQL server. I need to return the connection string so I can split it using ";" as a delimiter. I only need the Source data property from the string. I've found about ten ways of doing it wrong, but no way of successfully returning the string.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? As a general suggestion -- I find that Intellisence helps a lot. Declare a variable like Dim c as ODBCConnection. Then just type c. (c dot) and see what appears. There is a Connection property that sounds promising. Use a Debug.print to examine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the connection string from the `ODBCConnection.Connection` property of the `ODBCConnection` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked like a charm!